# Service get object null after init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have a service which stores certain object to share it between different controller. In this case I have the following code

```
    $rootScope.$on('controller.event', function(event, arg){
          self.backendConnectorService.getBackendObject('99901').then(function(object){
        if(object) {
            self.myService.selectDeselectObject(object);
            console.log(self.myService.getCurrentObject());
            $state.go('myApp.mainArea.appsArea.objects.wizards');
        }
    });
```

When I have my object I go to that state that will need the object initialized. The problem is that when I load the controller for that state, when I do `self.myService.getCurrentObject()` returns null. When I execute the `console.log` in the above code I'm getting the correct object. Why is this? I thought that services were singletons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to preserve data between states, you need to think in terms of using the built-in angular router or the 3rd party UI-Router (very popular, which I prefer). Then you can use resolves to resolve injections, or params to pass data along from one 'state' to another.

You're getting your 'object' then moving state - this initiates another controller, losing your object. Look at scotch.io's [angular router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router) page, which is quite helpful. You'd be better off using resolves in the state.config.js, then injecting it into your controller to use.

Comment: Can I resolve different objects depending on previous state? I mean if I go from state A to B I need ObjectTypeA and if I go from state C to B I need ObjectTypeB?

Comment: You can resolve -any- object that you would like, assuming you can.